# Get rows that were filtered out by a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

We have an existing reporting functionality. For the sake of simplicity let's assume below is the query:

```
select * from tab1
where
col1 = 'ABC'
and col2 = 'XYZ'
and col3 = 'KLM'
```

We now have a requirement to create an exception report. This report will contain all the records which were filtered out by the previous report, along with the reason (e.g. col1 <> 'ABC or col2 <> 'XYZ' and so on).

Of course, we can use the MINUS operator 3 times with 3 separate queries having each condition once compared with the original query to get differential records along with the precise reason why the row was filtered out. Like below query will give out all the rows that were filtered out with reason col1 <> 'ABC. We repeat this 2 more times to get the rows filtered out for the other 2 conditions.

```
select * from tab1
where
col2 = 'XYZ'
and col3 = 'KLM'
MINUS
select * from tab1
where
col1 = 'ABC'
and col2 = 'XYZ'
and col3 = 'KLM'
```

But our problem is that reporting query is much more complex with joins which also have conditions, and repeating a MINUS query for each condition seems very tedious and bad design.

Is there any way we can solve this problem with a simpler approach?

Comment: Your `MINUS` only needs the unfiltered query at the top and the filtered query at the bottom. I'm not sure why you would need "3 separate queries".

Comment: @JNevill I need 3 separate queries because I also need to provide a reason why a row was filtered out in the exception report. With a single MINUS query, I won't get the reason, just the rows that were filtered out.

Comment: There isn't a magic way to see why each row was filtered out. In your example it would be relatively simple to use minus or not to get all the excluded rows, and then just add a case expression to the select list that tests each condition separately. But it seems your real query is much more complicated and the exclusion could be buried in a join condition, which will make it much harder as the data involved might not be available to the select list. Without knowing you real data and query it's hard to say how you should approach this.

Comment: My approach to things like this is as follows: Gather all the data into a staging table with an extra,'exclusion_reason' column. Perform one or more operations on the staging table that add exclusion reasons for any rows that need to be excluded (this is useful as you can simplify your exclusion logic by breaking it down into smaller steps.) Then the main report SELECTs from the staging table WHERE exclusion_reason IS NULL and the exception report SELECTs from the staging table WHERE exclusion_reason IS NOT NULL.

Comment: If you need to run both queries with the same frequency, you may consider using `case` expression to generate as much boolean columns as you and then apply filters on these columns. This will allow to identify if some filtering expression true or false

Answer (score 1):

Just put NOT round your filtering conditions:

```
select * from tab1
where
NOT (
  col1 = 'ABC'
  and col2 = 'XYZ'
  and col3 = 'KLM'
```

)

Comment: This will not consider `null` values

Comment: So to fix this issue you may use dummy correlated subquery with `not exists` selecting from `dual` table: `where not exists (select 'nothing' from dual where <original condition>)`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f01088c6b28dcb8faeb5d21c7ff70312)

Answer (score 0):

With sample data like this:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select  1 "ID", 'ABC' "COL_1", 'X' "COL_2", 'KLM' "COL_3"   From Dual Union All
            Select  2 "ID", 'ABC' "COL_1", 'XYZ' "COL_2", 'KLM' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
            Select  3 "ID", 'A' "COL_1", 'XYZ' "COL_2", 'KLM' "COL_3"   From Dual Union All
            Select  4 "ID", 'ABC' "COL_1", 'XYZ' "COL_2", 'K' "COL_3"   From Dual Union All
            Select  5 "ID", 'ABC' "COL_1", 'XYZ' "COL_2", 'KLM' "COL_3" From Dual 
        )
--          ID COL_1 COL_2 COL_3
--  ---------- ----- ----- -----
--           1 ABC   X     KLM   
--           2 ABC   XYZ   KLM   
--           3 A     XYZ   KLM   
--           4 ABC   XYZ   K     
--           5 ABC   XYZ   KLM
```

Your report data would look like:

```sql
SELECT  * 
FROM    tbl
WHERE   COL_1 = 'ABC' and COL_2 = 'XYZ' And COL_3 = 'KLM'
--          ID COL_1 COL_2 COL_3
--  ---------- ----- ----- -----
--           2 ABC   XYZ   KLM   
--           5 ABC   XYZ   KLM
```

If you want to get the excluded rows with the explanation than maybe you should consider something similar to this:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.COL_1 <> 'ABC' THEN 'COL_1 not = ABC'
        WHEN t1.COL_2 <> 'XYZ' THEN 'COL_2 not = XYZ'
        WHEN t1.COL_3 <> 'KLM' THEN 'COL_3 not = KLM'
    ELSE
        'OK'
    END "STATUS"
FROM
    tbl t1
--
--          ID COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 STATUS        
--  ---------- ----- ----- ----- ---------------
--           1 ABC   X     KLM   COL_2 not = XYZ 
--           2 ABC   XYZ   KLM   OK              
--           3 A     XYZ   KLM   COL_1 not = ABC 
--           4 ABC   XYZ   K     COL_3 not = KLM 
--           5 ABC   XYZ   KLM   OK
```

... and if you add the where clause checking the STATUS <> 'OK' ...

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.COL_1 <> 'ABC' THEN 'COL_1 not = ABC'
        WHEN t1.COL_2 <> 'XYZ' THEN 'COL_2 not = XYZ'
        WHEN t1.COL_3 <> 'KLM' THEN 'COL_3 not = KLM'
    ELSE
        'OK'
    END "STATUS"
FROM
    tbl t1
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.COL_1 <> 'ABC' THEN 'COL_1 not = ABC'
        WHEN t1.COL_2 <> 'XYZ' THEN 'COL_2 not = XYZ'
        WHEN t1.COL_3 <> 'KLM' THEN 'COL_3 not = KLM'
    ELSE
        'OK'
    END <> 'OK'
```

... then the result would be ...

```sql
--          ID COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 STATUS        
--  ---------- ----- ----- ----- ---------------
--           1 ABC   X     KLM   COL_2 not = XYZ 
--           3 A     XYZ   KLM   COL_1 not = ABC 
--           4 ABC   XYZ   K     COL_3 not = KLM
```

I don't know the complexity of your actual context, but maybe you could do something like this. This is, also, a simplified answer not considering possible null issues or double/tripple differencies between the data. But you can get a picture and, maybe, find your own solution. Regards...

Comment: This will return`OK` if all three columns are `null`, which is, of course, incorrect. And after the issue is fixed, this will output only the first failed condition

Comment: Well, I'm glad you agree with my remarks in the last paragraph below the code. (quote) This is, also, a simplified answer not considering possible null issues or double/tripple differencies between the data. (end quote). Regards...